# If enums are implicitly static, why are they able to make use of the "this" keyword internally?

Tags: java, static, enums

Please forgive the beginner-level question, but I'm confused by the implicit static status of enums.

On one hand, you can't declare them within methods because they are implicitly static, and you can reference them from a static context like any other static class.. but on the other, internally, they refer to themselves as "this" as though they were an instance.

Code sample:

```
public class EnumTest {

  enum Seasons{
      SUMMER,
      FALL,
      WINTER,
      SPRING;

      public String toString()
      {
          switch(this)
          {
              case SUMMER:
                  return "Hot Summer";
              case FALL:
                  return "Colorful Fall";
              case WINTER:
                  return "Crisp Winter";
              case SPRING:
                  return "Allergy Season";
              default
                  return "wth?";

          }
      }
  }
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   System.out.println(EnumTest.Seasons.SUMMER.toString());
}

}
```

Note how within toString() in the enum definition, there is a switch on "this".

Within the static method main, the Enum is accessed in typical static class manner.

I know that enums are a special type of class, but I'm still trying to understand the reasons for some of their unconventional quirks.

Is there some sort of Factory-pattern type of auto-construction going on when an enum constant is referenced?  At exactly what point does it transition from being a static class to an instance?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `this` within a static class.

Comment: `public String toString()` is an instance method, so `this` is always valid inside of that.

Comment: "At exactly what point does it transition from being a static class to an instance?".  That question is non sensical.  Nothing transitions from being static to an instance.  You can have an instance of a static class, but nothing is transitioning there.

Comment: `case SPRING: return "Allergy Season";` Too true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constants defined in the enum class are the only things that are implicitly `static`.  It's close to (but not quite equivalent to):

```
public static final Seasons SUMMER = new Seasons();
public static final Seasons FALL = new Seasons();
public static final Seasons WINTER = new Seasons();
public static final Seasons SPRING = new Seasons();
```

This allows you to write code such as `Seasons.SUMMER`.

The rest of the class body is like a normal class body - `public String toString()` is not implicitly `static`, therefore it has access to `this`.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That also explains why you cannot instantiate the nested  enum outside of the class as you could a normal static nested class (e.g. EnumTest.Seasons=new EnumTest().new Seasons(); will not compile,) and yet you can reference the Enum constants from outside of the class like static data members of that class, assigning their pre-constructed values to a variable of type OuterClass.EnumType (EnumTest.Seasons in this case.)
It's kind of like a Multiton pattern applied to a nested class, then, isn't it?
This was very helpful.  Enums have been a weak spot of mine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the enum constants as statically declared objects like here:

```
class A {

    public final static A FOO = new A ("FOO");
    public final static A BAR = new A ("BAR");

    private final String text;

    private A(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.text;
    }

}
```

Although statically declared, the objects for each of the constants can provide non-static methods you can call.

Comment: constants in Java are `static final`, not just `static`.

Comment: PS: Why not just edit and add an obvious omission? ;-)